# How to pass value to UILabel, swift?

Tags: swift, uilabel

Would like to take the value from oneRep.description and pass it to my UILabel named oneRepLabel to be displayed on my UI.

```
    NSLog("Weight = \(weight.text)")
    NSLog("Reps = \(reps.text)")

        //initialize and set one rep max variable with formula
    var oneRep: Double = round(weightDouble * (1 + repsDouble/30))

    println("\(oneRep.description)")

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`oneRepLabel.text = oneRep.description`

or alternatively

`oneRepLabel.text = "\(oneRep)"`